# How can I read Excel Sheet from Google Drive and apply Search on that data in PHP?

Tags: php, excel, google-docs

I want to read my **excel sheet** from **Google Drive** and then apply search feature on that data.

Could anyone help me **1st step** read excel sheet from google drive **2nd step** apply search feature on that data in PHP.

Comment: What steps have you tried? What code have you written? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please visit the help centre and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). No one here is going to write your code for you - show us what you have tried, and what did not work.